# Google Datastore - how to check for the expiry of entitie of a kind regarding a date property comparing with the current time and date

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I am building an app in google app engine. I am storing entities of a kind with multiple properties and one of them is date and time property.

I need to check whether that date and time property exceeds or "expires" by comparing with the current date and time.

I do not prefer polling.

I am thinking about writing a daemon which continuously scans through all of the entities to check whether it is expired or not.

The point is, i need to send push notification if one of the entity is "Expired."

I may be totally wrong about this concept. Please suggest a better way.

Comment: sounds expensive..... Why not just save the "time since epoch" and GQL search for models with a value that is more/less then the value that would invalidate it, e.g. SELECT * FROM Contact_Info_Entry where AGE > 12345

Comment: Instead of scanning through the entire database, is there a better way to know when a specific entity "expires"?

Comment: Index the "date_expire" or "age" property (whatever you choose to use), and add a filter to your query. The Datastore will only return entities that match this query. It's very efficient.

Comment: well, you could create an entity and at the same time create a task that is timed to execute at the point at which the entity would expire and then "expire" the entity.

Comment: passing in a query is not the same as "scanning the entire database" btw. well, it is but it won't cost you the same as loading up then looking at every record in turn

Comment: But my app will be creating too many of these entities like 1 million in a day may be. So can app engine handle such a load and how can I do it efficiently..?

Comment: Most of the entities are supposed to be expired in 5 to 10 days or more

Comment: I think I just found a solution https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Comment: 1 million a day is OK I think :P

Comment: I have considered the options you have suggested but still I am in a dilemma.
The thing is there will be like thousands of entries into the db each with different date/time of expiry.
I need to setup an efficient mechanism in server side to check if an entity has expired and then perform an action.
Is the "deferred library" a solution for this ?

Comment: Not really, as it only allows you to easily create a task and defer it to a later time. It won't check if the entity has expired, only pause until you've asked it to run. So it might be fine. But you can have many tasks queued up, probably one for each entity. But as Andrei noted, you can do it however you want to as long as you have the $$ so paging through all the items is perfectly possible, if inefficient. Do your entities take more then 30 days to expire?

Comment: No I think it will be fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that you might consider:

1. Run a [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) which will periodically query the Datastore for expired entities and send notifications.
2. When you add an entity, create [a task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Using_push_queues) to notify a user when it expires. You can set an ETA on a task. This option is only available if your entities expire in less than 30 days.

Comment: But is it suitable for 1 million entries per day considering the worst case

Comment: It's only limited by your imagination (and your budget). Modules/backends and tasks are easily scalable.